# How to Add iamRoleStatements to S3 Trigger Bucket in Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

When I am adding the following code in **serverless.yml** file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: [REGION]
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref": [BUCKET NAME] }, "/*" ] ] }
```

On deployment, I am getting **“The CloudFormation template is invalid: Circular dependency between resources:”**

I am using **boto3** with **python3** to get the private file that is uploaded to the S3 bucket after the trigger event so like to give the permission to **Lambda function** for that bucket.

Comment: I think this is really just a CloudFormation question, not specifically a serverless framework question. Have you looked at the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680599/amazon-web-services-tag-a-s3-bucket-with-its-own-name-within-a-cloudformation

Comment: No, mainly I am doing something wrong in the **serverless.yml** file that's why included serverless framework.

Comment: But it's a CloudFormation error. Isn't serverless.yml just a CloudFormation template file? I would search for how to solve that error in CloudFormation and not narrow down your search unnecessarily to serverless framework.

Comment: But the code that I shared is in the serverless.yml file and serverless framework is converting that to CloudFormation template.

Comment: I don't think serverless framework is converting that to a CloudFormation template. It already is a CloudFormation template. That's all it is.

Comment: @MarkB Don't think so as when you run the command **sls deploy -v** it creates a **.serverless** folder and also creates **cloudformation-template-update-stack.json**. And this **json** file contains the **CloudFormation template**.

Comment: I guess it's converting the yml to json for some reason. I don't know why it would need to though since CloudFormation accepts yml templates. Anyway, the serverless.yml file is documented as using CloudFormation syntax, so you should be able to treat it just like a CloudFormation template file and not worry about it getting converted to a JSON file.

Comment: cloudformation-template-update-stack.json contains more information than severless.yml. So it's not a simple yaml-to-json conversion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue and I spent hours on it. Finally I found a solution: do **NOT** ref the bucket.

Change

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: [REGION]
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref": [BUCKET NAME] }, "/*" ] ] }
```

to

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: [REGION]
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::<s3-bucket-name>", "/*" ] ] }
```

Or even simpler:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: [REGION]
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::<s3-bucket-name>/*"
```

Comment: You saved me thousands of hours! So sad that the main documentation is missing so basic stuff..

Comment: What if BucketName is dynamic and changes depending on stage?

Comment: [Tyler Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862862/tyler-long) what does that `*` star means?

Comment: @RahulAhire it means all the resources under that bucket.